# Session loses data on page refresh (php, apache vhost, IE)

Tags: php, apache, internet-explorer, session, browser

On IE my session does not work as i desire.

the script::

```
<? 
session_start();

echo "Testing sessions " . $_SESSION['test'] . " working";

$_SESSION['test'] = 'are';
?>
```

1. load page (displays 'Testing sessions working')
2. refresh page (displays 'Testing are sessions working') at least i hope for this outcome..

in Chrome it works 
in fireFox it works
in Ie it does not work (depends)

situation 1 fails (IE)
http://mysite.d.my-domain.com/  (defaults to index.php)

situation 2 works (IE)
http://prj.my-domain.com/mysite/D  (defaults to same index.php)

both link to the same physical location on my FreeBSD / apache 2.2 server.

if i place session_id('someID') it works but session_id is not what i need.

should i look from :
- PHP (this is server based so i see no reason for the session failure)
- apache (how would this be influenced by the browser)
- IE (would the browser to recognise one vhost from another? )

please help for all searching has been for naught

Comment: Do you really need to put the `$_SESSION['test']` after those string? Why not instantiate it before the string.

Comment: if i put it before the echo part it would always work for it would be stored inside the session before i output this. this way you'd only see the word "are" in the output on the page refresh.. what in fact is the part that failes in IE in certain cases

Comment: both situations are defined in a <VirtualHost *> section of apache

Comment: Did you change session settings?

Comment: no i did not change anything.. i just use two different routes to the same location which result in inconsitent behaviour from IE

Answer (score 1):

After some long searches i finally found the sollutions.

apparantly IE does not cope well with the underscore "`_`" character in the name of my subdomain.

but changing `mysite_com.mydomain.com` to `mysite-com.mydomain.com` the session started working again.

so in fact it was url that was messing things up. but only as the subdomain part for 
`mydomain.com/mysite_com` did work.